# How to submit a TimerTask to another Timer when it 's running

Tags: java, timer, timertask

In a `run` method of a TimerTask object, How can I submit the timerTask itself to another Timer. 
When the timerTask is running, I should do a judge and decide whether it can do some work. If it not meet the condition, I should cancel it and put it to another Timer.
Code of my TimerTask is like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        if (flag) {
           // do something
        } else {
           new Timer().schedule(this, 1000 * 60)；
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Will it work?

Comment: Posting some code would help

Comment: You should only use one `Timer` and then monitor the condition from external, for example from a `Thread`, a `Runnable` or another `Timer`. Then stop, cancel, re-assign, start the timer as necessary from your external monitor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use one `Timer` and then monitor the condition from external, for example from a `Thread`, a `Runnable` or another `Timer`. Then stop, cancel, re-assign, start the timer as necessary from your external monitor.

---

Here's a `TimerTask`:

```
public class OurTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

And here's the monitor:

```
public Monitor implements Runnable() {
    private Timer mTimerToMonitor;

    public Monitor(Timer timerToMonitor) {
        this.mTimerToMonitor = timerToMonitor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (!flag) {
                // Cancel the timer and start a new
                this.mTimerToMonitor.cancel();
                this.mTimerToMonitor = new Timer();
                this.mTimerToMonitor.schedule(...);
            }

            // Wait a second
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in practice your `Monitor` should also be able to get canceled from outside, currently it runs infinitely.

And this is how you could call it:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new OurTask(), ...);

Thread monitorThread = new Thread(new Monitor(timer));
monitorThread.start();
```

---

Also note that instead of using `Runnable`, `Timer` and `Thread` it could be worth taking a look into the new **Java 8** stuff, especially the interface [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and classes implementing it.